# Where is this script going wrong

Tags: bash, awk

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash
function labels2 () {
    awk '
    /[0-9]/{
    print substr($3,length($3)-11), $3
    }' $@ | /bin/sort -u  | awk '{print "BUILD: " NR, $2}'
}

function labels () {
    awk '
    /[0-9]/{
    BL[$3] = substr($3,length($3)-11)
    }
    END {
    asort(BL)
    for (i in BL) {
        print i, BL[i]
    }
    }' $@
}


labels $@
exit 0

for a in $@
do
    labels $@ | gawk '
    /BUILD:/ {
    BUILD[$2] = $3
    BUILDCNT ++
    next
    }
    /[0-9]/ {
    DATEd[$3] = $1
    TIMEd[$3] = $2
    MODULESd[$3] = $4
    CASESd[$3] = $5
    FAILEDd[$3] = $6
    COVERd[$3] = $7
    LOCd[$3] = $8
    }
    END {
    SUBSYSTEM=substr(FILENAME, 1, length(FILENAME)-7)
    LABEL= "\"" toupper(SUBSYSTEM) "\""
    print "{"
        print "subsystem: " LABEL ","
        print "    date: {"
        print "        label: " LABEL ","
        print "        data: ["
        for (i = 0 ; i <= BUILDCNT; i ++ ) {
            B=BUILD[i]
            if (DATEd[B]) { print "            [" i ", \"" DATEd[B] "\"]," }
        }
        print "        ]"
        print "    },"
    }
    ' - $a
done
```

And this text input file cos.txt

```
2011-01-22 22:12 P16A22_110114072915 22 1312 75 13.55 1399
2011-01-22 22:12 P16A22_110114072915 22 1312 75 13.55 1399
```

now to my question, why is it printing out

```
1 110114072915
2 110114072915
```

instead of

```
{ 
subsystem: "COS",
  date: {
        label: "CAS",
        data: [[1,"110114072915"],[2,110114072915]]
}
```

**EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I did as you guys said, and it partly worked. But now it comes on the form

```
1 110114072915
2 110114072965{
subsystem: "COS",
    date: {
        label: "COS",
        data: [
            [0, "3"],
        ]
    },
```

And not on the form

```
{ 
subsystem: "COS",
  date: {
        label: "CAS",
        data: [[1,"110114072915"],[2,110114072915]]
}
```

How can I change this? Also I want to do so that they come in order

in the array =)

Thanks yet again for your help =)

Comment: if you're going to be dealing with JSON, you may want to take a look at [`jsawk`](https://github.com/micha/jsawk) and get away with building something custom from scratch.

Comment: `exit 0`? That would seem to skip the for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of

```
labels $@
exit 0      <-- you told exit after the function "labels"... ;)
```